# Can I use Examples in Background block?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I need background to be run with 2 different roles.
I'm not allowed to do this:

```
 Background:
    Given I login as existing user with role "<role>"
    And I choose to create new Account

    Examples: 
        | role          |   
        | Standard User |
        | Site Admin    |
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate pieces of behaviour here so do a scenario, or even a feature for each one.

In most applications different rules will apply for users and admins, and in many systems and even different ui's will be used.

A top rule for scenario writing is that its much better to have lots of simple scenarios than a few complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `Background`..  you can use `Scenario Outline` in feature:

For example:

```
Scenario Outline:

 Given I login as existing user with role "<role>"
 And I choose to create new Account

    Examples: 
        | role          |   
        | Standard User |
        | Site Admin    |
```